# Guzzle asynch request not working

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that I installed via **composer** and failing to do something relatively straightforward.

I might be misunderstanding the [documentation](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#asynchronous-requests) but essentially what I'm wanting to do is run a `POST` request to a server and continue executing code without waiting for a response. Here's what I have :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(/*baseUrl, and auth credentials here*/);
$client->post('runtime/process-instances', [
    'future'=>true,
    'json'=> $data // is an array
]);
die("I'm done with the call");
```

Now lets say the `runtime/process-instances` runs for about 5mn, I will not get the die message before those 5mn are up... When instead I want it right after the message is **sent** to the server.

Now I don't have access to the server so I can't have the server respond before running the execution. I just need to ignore the response.

Any help is appreciated.

**Things I've tried:**

```
$client->post(/*blabla*/)->then(function ($response) {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible in Guzzle to send a request and immediately exit. Asynchronous requests require that you wait for them to complete. If you do not, the request will not get sent.

Also note that you are using `post` instead of `postAsync`, the former is a synchronous (blocking) request. To asynchronously send a post request, use the latter. In your code example, by changing `post` to `postAsync` the process will exit before the request is complete, but the target will not receive that request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a low [timeout](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#timeout)?

Comment: The default is no timeout.

Comment: I did not think of that. It feels very hacky though. Is there a reason why the asynch doesn't work as expected? Or am I misunderstanding what the asynch functionalities are meant to do?

Comment: @D.Mill async in PHP is to me mostly for making several requests at the same time.